# Jquery UI live(): Focusing on events other than 'click'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code shows Jquery UI Date Picker upon click of a (initially hidden) textbox. Anyone know how to allow the 'tab' button to activate it as well? The datepicker class in this case applies to a textbox. Many users would use tab instead of clicking, and it doesn't work right now..

```
$(function() { 
    $('.datepicker').live('click', function () {
            $(this).datepicker({showOn: 'both'}).focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "allow the 'tab' button to activate", I assume you mean hitting tab to shift focus into the text box? If that's the case, [the `live` handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works on the `focus` event too, so you could just change your code to catch the `focus` event instead of `click` (`click` will cause the field to get focus & fire then too).

**Edit:** ..oops, re-reading the code, my hasty example would cause an infinite focus loop, try this instead:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#ReferenceNumber').live('focus', function () {
        var picker = $(this).datepicker({showOn: ''});
        picker.datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked - but it doesn't go away. It stays focused..any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to delegate on keydown.

```
$('body').live('keydown',function(e){
        //Keycode 9 is the tab key
        if(e.keyCode == 9) {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({showOn: 'both'}).focus();
        }
});
```